# react-redux: infinite loop on dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, flux

I have a sample application that loads entries from a Spring boot backend. However, my approach leads to an infinite loop that I cannot explain to myself.

api.ts

```
class CommonApi extends BaseApi {
  public loadEntries = () => this.get('http://localhost:8080/radars/development/entries') as Promise<any>;
}
```

entriesSlice.ts

```
interface EntriesState {
    map: {}
}

const initialState: EntriesState = {
    map: {}
};

export const entriesSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'entries',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        getEntries: (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
            state.map = action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export const { getEntries } = entriesSlice.actions;

export const getEntriesAction = (): AppThunk => dispatch => {
    return commonApi.loadEntries().then(payload => {
        const newPayload: any[] = [];

        payload.map((entry: any) => {
            return newPayload.push({
                label: entry.label,
                quadrant: toSegment(entry.category),
                ring: toRing(entry.status)
            })
        })

        dispatch(getEntries(newPayload));
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error('error: ', err)
    })
};

export const entriesObject = (state: RootState) => state.entries.map;

export default entriesSlice.reducer;
```

I think I've found out that this line in entriesSlice.ts causes the error, but I dont know why:

state.map = action.payload;

App.tsx

```
import { entriesObject, getEntriesAction } from "../../features/entries/entriesSlice";
import { config1Object, getConfig1Action } from "../../features/config1/config1Slice";

function App() {
  const config1 = useSelector(config1Object) as any;
  const entries = useSelector(entriesObject) as any;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getConfig1Action());
    dispatch(getEntriesAction());
  }, [config1, entries, dispatch]);

  return (
    <Container>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Chart config={config1} entries={entries} />
      </TabPanel>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `entries` as a dependency to your `useEffect` - every time `getEntriesAction` is dispatched it fetches entries and creates a new object in state, which tells react that `entries` has been updated (it's a new object with a new reference), which reruns the `useEffect`, which dispatches `getEntriesAction` again, which... leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: That fixed my problem. But what if entries do change? For example by adding a new entry? Doesn't useEffect have to be executed again?

Comment: Well it depends on what you need to do when `entries` update, but I'm guessing you probably don't want to reload them (and/or config) from the API when they do? If you do need to do some things when entries update, but not reload them, you could just move those things to a separate `useEffect` that has `entries` as a dependency. Or, you could just put an if condition around the reload so that it doesn't happen on any update to `entries`.

Comment: Users of the dashboard can add new entries to the chart, so I need to update the view after a new entry was added.